# Get DLL path at runtime

Tags: c++, dll

I want to get a **dll's** directory (or file) path from within its code. (not the program's .exe file path)

I've tried a few methods I've found:
`GetCurrentDir` - gets the current directory path.
`GetModuleFileName` - gets the executable's path.

So how can i find out in which dll the code is in ?
I'm looking for something similar to C#'s `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly`

Answer (score 137, accepted):

You can use the `GetModuleHandleEx` function and get the handle to a static function in your DLL. You'll find more information [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683200%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

After that you can use `GetModuleFileName` to get the path from the handle you just obtained. More information on that call is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683197%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

A complete example:

```
char path[MAX_PATH];
HMODULE hm = NULL;

if (GetModuleHandleEx(GET_MODULE_HANDLE_EX_FLAG_FROM_ADDRESS | 
        GET_MODULE_HANDLE_EX_FLAG_UNCHANGED_REFCOUNT,
        (LPCSTR) &functionInThisDll, &hm) == 0)
{
    int ret = GetLastError();
    fprintf(stderr, "GetModuleHandle failed, error = %d\n", ret);
    // Return or however you want to handle an error.
}
if (GetModuleFileName(hm, path, sizeof(path)) == 0)
{
    int ret = GetLastError();
    fprintf(stderr, "GetModuleFileName failed, error = %d\n", ret);
    // Return or however you want to handle an error.
}

// The path variable should now contain the full filepath for this DLL.
```

Comment: This technique worked perfectly for me. The accepted answer using __ImageBase caused my dll to crash during initialization with VC11. Just linking in the code referencing __ImageBase caused some CRT or ATL initialization code to crash with 0xC0000005.

Comment: It is interesting to note that the `lpModuleName` in the presence of the `GET_MODULE_HANDLE_EX_FLAG_FROM_ADDRESS` flag might not only be the local function. It might be also the address of **a (local) static variable**.

Comment: +1; great answer (just made use of it); superior to the accepted one.

Comment: [PathRemoveFileSpec](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773748(VS.85).aspx) is also your friend.

Comment: I agree--using GetModuleHandleEx and GetModuleFileName seems to be the best way to answer this question. I just made a gist, https://gist.github.com/pwm1234/05280cf2e462853e183d, that packages the code from mkaes into a standalone function, get_module_path and shows how to call it from anywhere.

Comment: I had to add `#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0501` to my `stdafx.h` as my copy of `winbase.h` only defines `GET_MODULE_HANDLE_EX_FLAG_FROM_ADDRESS` if the OS ver > `0x0500`. This is noted in the MS docs for `GetModuleHandleEx( )`

Comment: Worked for me on a win32 dll on Windows 10 64 bit but I also had use wchar_t instead of char and  wchar_t full_file_path[MAX_PATH]; and cast to (LPCWSTR)&functionInThisDll rather than (LPCSTR) &functionInThisDll

Comment: There is an issue with this solution that if the DLL cannot be loaded (due to dependency issues) the function GetModuleHandleEx will fail - making the dll appear not 'installed' while it is

Comment: @NoamRathaus: If the DLL cannot load, then its code does not run, and "get the DLL's file path from within its code" is moot.

Answer (score 46):

```
EXTERN_C IMAGE_DOS_HEADER __ImageBase;
```

....

```
TCHAR   DllPath[MAX_PATH] = {0};
GetModuleFileName((HINSTANCE)&__ImageBase, DllPath, _countof(DllPath));
```

Comment: Any comments about future compatibility of `__ImageBase` variable?

Comment: __ ImageBase is variable of type IMAGE_DOS_HEADER, and this is coming first in the PE (portable executable format). It's a windows structure and is available only under Windows. In my opinion is safe to use and will not be changed in the future. An alternative will be GetModuleHandle but needs dll name.

Comment: I just read about this global variable. I am aware about PE headers, but didn't know about this. Thanks!

Comment: It is used in MS sample code, so should be safe.  For example, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd742738(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Why not use GetModuleHandle instead of __ImageBase?

Comment: @AgnelKurian That requires another function call and it should return the pointer at `__ImageBase`.

Comment: Why donť you just use what you get in DllMain instead of __ImageBase?

Comment: Why use `GetModuleFileNameW` instead of `GetModuleFileNameA` ?

Comment: @HaseeBMir Because the OS is unicode and you can have app in folder that contains unicode chars. GetModuleFileNameW is for unicode, in example I have used WCHAR. However if you really "need" the path as char array you can use GetModuleFileNameA.

Comment: Ok but why dont system decide it they have Macros for it like GetModuleFileName which checks for `ifdef _UNICODE` and use `GetModuleFileNameW` version otherwise will use ASCII version

Comment: Yes, you are right. It should be generic. However I strongly advise you to use Unicode. You cannot control the filesystem, user can and will do anything.

Answer (score 24):

`GetModuleFileName()` works fine from inside the DLL's codes. Just be sure NOT to set the first parameter to `NULL`, as that will get the filename of the calling process. You need to specify the DLL's actual module instance instead. You get that as an input parameter in the DLL's `DllEntryPoint()` function, just save it to a variable somewhere for later use when needed.

Comment: GetModuleHandle will give you the same handle as the input parameter to DllEntryMain.

Comment: This seems the simplest answer, and it works too. Agnel means DllMain() btw, instead of DllEntryMain().

Answer (score 5):

Here's a Unicode, revised version of the top voted answer:

```
CStringW thisDllDirPath()
{
    CStringW thisPath = L"";
    WCHAR path[MAX_PATH];
    HMODULE hm;
    if( GetModuleHandleExW( GET_MODULE_HANDLE_EX_FLAG_FROM_ADDRESS | 
                            GET_MODULE_HANDLE_EX_FLAG_UNCHANGED_REFCOUNT,
                            (LPWSTR) &thisDllDirPath, &hm ) )
    {
        GetModuleFileNameW( hm, path, MAX_PATH );
        PathRemoveFileSpecW( path );
        thisPath = CStringW( path );
        if( !thisPath.IsEmpty() && 
            thisPath.GetAt( thisPath.GetLength()-1 ) != '\\' ) 
            thisPath += L"\\";
    }
    else if( _DEBUG ) std::wcout << L"GetModuleHandle Error: " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
    
    if( _DEBUG ) std::wcout << L"thisDllDirPath: [" << CStringW::PCXSTR( thisPath ) << L"]" << std::endl;       
    return thisPath;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Provided you implemented the following dll entry point: (usually dllmain.cpp)

```
BOOL APIENTRY DllMain( HMODULE hModule,
                   DWORD  ul_reason_for_call,
                   LPVOID lpReserved
                 )
```

You can simply do:

```
switch (ul_reason_for_call)
{ 
case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
{
    TCHAR dllFilePath[512 + 1] = { 0 };
    GetModuleFileNameA(hModule, dllFilePath, 512)
}
    break;
case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH: break;
...
```

dllFilePath will then contain the path to where the current dll code was loaded. In this case hModule is passed by the process loading the dll.

Answer (score 2):

Imho, Remy Lebau’s answer is the best, but lacks like all other answers to render the directory of the DLL. I quote the original question: “I want to get a dll's directory (or file) path from within its code. (not the program's .exe file path).”

As Remy and Jean-Marc Volle pointed out, the DLL entry function `DllMain` usually contained in dllmain.cpp provides the handle to the DLL. This handle is often necessary, so it will be saved in a global variable `hMod`. I also add variables of type `std::wstring` to store the fully qualified name and the parent path of the DLL.

```
HMODULE hMod;
std::wstring PathAndName;
std::wstring OnlyPath;
BOOL APIENTRY DllMain( HMODULE hModule, DWORD ul_reason_for_call, LPVOID lpReserved)
{
  switch (ul_reason_for_call)
  {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH: case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH: case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
       case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
     break;
  }
  hMod = hModule;
  const int BUFSIZE = 4096;
  wchar_t buffer[BUFSIZE];
  if (::GetModuleFileNameW(hMod, buffer, BUFSIZE - 1) <= 0)
  {
    return TRUE;
  }

  PathAndName = buffer;

  size_t found = PathAndName.find_last_of(L"/\\");
  OnlyPath = PathAndName.substr(0, found);

  return TRUE;
}
```

These global variables can be used inside the DLL.

Answer (score 1):

Try [GetModuleFileName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683197%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) function.

Answer (score 1):

For Delphi users:

```
SysUtils.GetModuleName(hInstance);              //Works; hInstance is a special global variable
SysUtils.GetModuleName(0);                      //Fails; returns the name of the host exe process
SysUtils.GetModuleName(GetModuleFilename(nil)); //Fails; returns the name of the host exe process
```

In case your Delphi doesn't have SysUtils.GetModuleName, it is declared as:

```
function GetModuleName(Module: HMODULE): string;
var
   modName: array[0..32767] of Char; //MAX_PATH is for a single filename; paths can be up to 32767 in NTFS - or longer.
begin
   {
      Retrieves the fully qualified path for the file that contains the specified module. 
      The module must have been loaded by the current process.
   }
   SetString(Result, modName, GetModuleFileName(Module, modName, Length(modName)));
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to achieve something similar, except wanted to make similar function into one .dll - but then you cannot use __ImageBase, since it's specific to that .dll where function is located. I've even tried to override using approach

```
GetDllPath( HMODULE hDll = (HMODULE) __ImageBase)
```

But that did not work our either. (For some reason returns application path after that.)

Then I've figured out - why I don't use VirtualQuery, and use function pointer and get HMODULE from there. But again - how to get function pointer of caller ?

And now it gets back to call stack determination - I won't bother you with all dirty details, just follow links of referred links.

Here is whole code snapshot:

```
//
//  Originated from: https://sourceforge.net/projects/diagnostic/
//
//  Similar to windows API function, captures N frames of current call stack.
//  Unlike windows API function, works with managed and native functions.
//
int CaptureStackBackTrace2( 
    int FramesToSkip,                   //[in] frames to skip, 0 - capture everything.
    int nFrames,                        //[in] frames to capture.
    PVOID* BackTrace                    //[out] filled callstack with total size nFrames - FramesToSkip
)
{
#ifdef _WIN64
    CONTEXT ContextRecord;
    RtlCaptureContext(&ContextRecord);

    UINT iFrame;
    for (iFrame = 0; iFrame < (UINT)nFrames; iFrame++)
    {
        DWORD64 ImageBase;
        PRUNTIME_FUNCTION pFunctionEntry = RtlLookupFunctionEntry(ContextRecord.Rip, &ImageBase, NULL);

        if (pFunctionEntry == NULL)
        {
            if (iFrame != -1)
                iFrame--;           // Eat last as it's not valid.
            break;
        }

        PVOID HandlerData;
        DWORD64 EstablisherFrame;
        RtlVirtualUnwind(0 /*UNW_FLAG_NHANDLER*/,
            ImageBase,
            ContextRecord.Rip,
            pFunctionEntry,
            &ContextRecord,
            &HandlerData,
            &EstablisherFrame,
            NULL);

        if(FramesToSkip > (int)iFrame)
            continue;

        BackTrace[iFrame - FramesToSkip] = (PVOID)ContextRecord.Rip;
    }
#else
    //
    //  This approach was taken from StackInfoManager.cpp / FillStackInfo
    //  http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11221/Easy-Detection-of-Memory-Leaks
    //  - slightly simplified the function itself.
    //
    int regEBP;
    __asm mov regEBP, ebp;

    long *pFrame = (long*)regEBP;               // pointer to current function frame
    void* pNextInstruction;
    int iFrame = 0;

    //
    // Using __try/_catch is faster than using ReadProcessMemory or VirtualProtect.
    // We return whatever frames we have collected so far after exception was encountered.
    //
    __try {
        for (; iFrame < nFrames; iFrame++)
        {
            pNextInstruction = (void*)(*(pFrame + 1));

            if (!pNextInstruction)     // Last frame
                break;

            if (FramesToSkip > iFrame)
                continue;

            BackTrace[iFrame - FramesToSkip] = pNextInstruction;
            pFrame = (long*)(*pFrame);
        }
    }
    __except (EXCEPTION_EXECUTE_HANDLER)
    {
    }

#endif //_WIN64
    iFrame -= FramesToSkip;
    if(iFrame < 0)
        iFrame = 0;

    return iFrame;
} //CaptureStackBackTrace2



//
//  Gets .dll full path or only directory.
//
CStringW GetDllPath( bool bPathOnly /* = false */ )
{
    void* pfunc = &GetDllPath;
    wchar_t path[MAX_PATH] = { 0 };
    MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION info;
    HMODULE hdll;

    CaptureStackBackTrace2(1, 2, &pfunc);

    // Get the base address of the module that holds the current function
    VirtualQuery(pfunc, &info, sizeof(MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION));

    // MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION::AllocationBase corresponds to HMODULE
    hdll = (HMODULE)info.AllocationBase;

    // Get the dll filename
    if ( !GetModuleFileName( hdll, path, MAX_PATH ) )
        return L"";

    if ( bPathOnly )
    {
        wchar_t* p = wcsrchr( path, '\\' );
        if ( p )
            *p = 0;
    }

    return path;
} //GetDllPath
```

Comment: Next to the error-prone stacktrace function, you return 'path' in GetDllPath(), which is local array, so destroyed upon return. This will crash.
Just using GetModuleFileName() with the DLL handle as passed in DllMain() (described above) works in 3 lines of code.

Comment: Use my code sample only if you want to place GetDllPath into shared dll and use it from other dlls.

Simpler approach would be to write GetDllPath  for each dll separately, but then you will have multiple copies of same function or same source code is included from multiple dlls - this is a solution as well of course.

Comment: But 'path' is created on the stack, and as soon as GetDllPath() returns this variable will disappear. So using the string is bound to crash, right?

Comment: Function itself creates copy of string to caller. Should not crash in theory.

Comment: I see 'wchar_t path', so it's on the stack. Then 'return path' which returns a pointer to a stack item. But indeed, I see an implicit CStringW as the return type, which probably makes the copy. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

I'm (in my case) comping those who revealed the easy DllMain method. The job was to find what is the machine bitness of the current thread running inside of a dll. To be absolutely sure I wanted also the name of running dll and exe. Name of caller is found by NULL parameter:

`char   exePat[MAX_PATH] = { 0 };   GetModuleFileName(NULL, exePat, MAX_PATH);`

Using the hModule of DllMain feels most complete and trustable way to find dll name and machine bitness.
Code was found so that to obtain the "machine" only module is needed.  Here is the part which brings up the name too for debugging purpose.

```
BOOL APIENTRY DllMain(HMODULE hModule, DWORD  reason,LPVOID lpReserved ) {

     char  path[MAX_PATH] = { 0 };
     GetModuleFileNameA(hModule, path, MAX_PATH);
     PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER startPoint = (PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER)hModule;
     PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS pNtHeaders = (PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS)((LPBYTE)startPoint + startPoint->e_lfanew);
     PIMAGE_FILE_HEADER fileHeader = &pNtHeaders->FileHeader;
     short machine = fileHeader->Machine;
     ////0x8664 is 64bit  0x14c is 32bit.
     int stop = 0;
     return TRUE;
 }
```

Answer (score -4):

```
HMODULE hmod = GetCurrentModule();
TCHAR szPath[MAX_PATH + 1] = 0;
DWORD dwLen = GetModuleFileHName(hmod, szPath, MAX_PATH);
```

Comment: This is going to give you the path the exe that loaded the dll, not the dll itself.