# Chrome extension - get full path

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

i build chrome extension and i use NPAPI to open exe file.
To open the file i need full path(C:\Program Files\test.exe).
I attach the "test.exe" to my project and i want to open it.
The problem is that i can't know where the file after the installation.
I need to get something like this:

```
C:\Users\**User Name**\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Extensions\**App Name**\**App Version**\test.exe
```

How can i get this?
(All I can found is the "App Name" and the "App Version")

Comment: The system environment variable `%LOCALAPPDATA%` should point to `C:\Users\**User Name**\AppData\Local`

Comment: Just a heads-up: If user is using Chrome profiles, then `Default` might not be `Default` (but I have no idea how you could solve this problem).

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6924195/get-dll-path-at-runtime