# Get relative path to current dll from working directory

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, dll

I'm using software that loads my .dll library
The sofware is located somewhere on my my hard drive, let's say:

```
C:\Program Files\UNICODE CHARS\(...)\123.exe
```

And my dll is located in:

```
C:\Program Files\UNICODE CHARS\(...)\Addons\Dlls\123.dll
```

Now I need to be able to perform some operations like fopen(), fclose() etc from inside of dll, passing PATH to dll as fopen parameter.

How to get relative path do 123.dll that will allow me to access this file with short, ansi path, possibly

```
Addons\Dlls\123.dll
```

Comment: Does: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6924332/168175 answer for you? (I was about to write exactly that as an answer!)

Comment: The EXE and DLL can retrieve their own full paths, you do not need to use relative paths (nor should you ever use relative paths).

Comment: (Close vote retracted.  However, Remy is right; relative paths are bad news.  Any particular reason you want the path to be short?)