# While debugging with Visual Studio, my application freezes on an external DLL call. How can I find the path to this DLL?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, kinect-sdk, azurekinect

I am debugging a Windows application on Visual Studio 2017 because my Azure Kinect application freezes after 20-30minutes of use. When I "pause" the debugger and check the call stack, I can see that the main thread is waiting for an operation happening on a separate thread. This second thread is executing a method defined by `k4a.dll`.

I have three versions of this dll on my operating system, and I am not sure which one my application is using. **Is there any way I can extract the path to the library (dll) from Visual Studio?**

[image]

(Notice:  I am *not* looking for answers that tell me to use tools like PE-Explorer or Depends. I want that information coming from Visual Studio as it could be finding another library in its scan path)

Comment: Have you tried this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6924332/6014330

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I am looking for something that I can do from within Visual Studio. Changing my code to get the information would be the last option here.

Comment: OK, this took longer than I thought and it was very silly...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out you just need to right-click the `Call Stack` window over the library name and select `Go To Module`.

A new window will pop-up with a path to all the libraries your application is using...

[image]

Modules window with the path for each library:

[image]